# OAuth 2.0 not working for server-side web application

Tags: php, google-api, oauth-2.0

I am trying to get `gmail` contacts using `Google contacts api`. For this i am using `OAuth 2.0`. For this i read their guide for using `OAuth 2.0` here. Broadly i followed these steps

1. Register my app with google and get a client id and client secret and registered my `redirect uri` with them
2. now i first created a file called `sample.php` on which if the user clicks on `get contacts` he is redirected to google confirmation page
3. now google asks for confirmation and if the user agrees to provide its contact details then he is redirected to the `redirect uri` with a `code`.
4. now i extract the code and make a post request to get the OAuth token and if i get the token i make a request for the contacts.

The code for the `sample.php` looks like this

```
<?php
$client_id="my client id";
$redirect_uri="http://localhost/htdocs/contacts/redirect.php";
echo <<<doc
<html>
<body>
<a href="http://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=$client_id&redirect_uri=$redirect_uri&scope=https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/&response_type=code">
get contacts
</a>
doc;
echo <<<doc
</body>
</html>
doc;
?>
```

the code for the `redirect.php` looks like this

```
<?php
$client_id="my client id";
$client_sec="my client secret ";  
$redirect_uri="http://localhost/htdocs/contacts/redirect.php";
$code=$_GET['code'];
$post="code=$code&client_id=$client_id&client_secret=$client_sec&redirect_uri=$redirect_uri&grant_type=authorization_code";
$post=urlencode($post);
 //the following curl request is made to get the authorization token
$ch=curl_init();
$url="https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token";
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
$json=curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $json;     // this is showing Required parameter is missing: grant_type Error 400
$res=json_decode($json,true);
print_r($res);   // this is just for debugging
$token=$res['access_token'];
echo $token;   // this is just for debugging
$url="https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?oauth_token=$token";
  //the following curl request is made to get the contacts
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,1);
$xml=curl_exec($ch);
echo $xml;
curl_close($ch);
$dom= new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$xpath=new DOMXPath($dom);
$path='//gd:email';
$nodes=$xpath->query($path);
echo $nodes->length."<br />";
foreach($nodes as $node)
{
$email=$node->attributes->getNamedItem('address')->nodeValue;
echo $email."<br />";
}
?>
```

now the problem is that step 4 fails. It goes well till the confirmation step and when i click `Allow access` i am redirected to my `redirect uri` but its saying

**Required parameter is missing: grant_type  Error 400**

now i dont understand this because i am providing the `grant_type` parameter. i looked in `firebug` and found out that a post request is being made but not the one which i intended. the post request that is being made is this
`https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/approval?xsrfsign=AC9jObYAAAAATkfm3uvx0sfsW7WVmB_FeRqVPLjDcTLz` and the status says `302 moved Temporarily`. I dont understand whats going on. have they changed something in the `OAuth workflow`? Need some help

---

**Edit**
As suggested bu **Ikke** i removed the space before `grant_type` and it worked. Now i can get the access token but still i am unable to get the contacts.(*i get an error as `Empty string supplied as input in htdocs\contacts\redirect.php on line 35` and `line 35` refers to `$dom->loadXML($xml)`; so it seems that the get request is not being made*) Moreover i am not able to see the post request being made in `firebug` (but surely its being made because i get the access token as the response). i also dont see the get request in `firebug` which i make after post request whats wrong?

---

**Update:**
the problem was that the request was on https and i was not using the appropriate headers for https. I used the correct headers and it worked.Problem solved? Maybe. Because i still dont understand why i am unable to see those get and post requests in `firebug's'` net` tab

Comment: Maybe it's a typo, but there is a space between the & and grant_type.

Comment: @Ikke thanks that worked.  Now i am able to get the `access token` but not the contacts yet. let me see if get the contacts also. Post it as an answer and i will mark it accepted. Thanks again

Comment: What do you mean by "unable to get the contacts"?

Comment: @ikke i mean that i am not getting the contacts page. I dont see the curl get request for the contacts being made  I get a message as `Empty string supplied as input in C:\xampp\htdocs\contacts\redirect.php on line 35` the line 35 refers to `$dom->loadXML($xml);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a space between the `&` and the `grant_type`. That could cause google not to recognize the parameter.

Comment: Thanks. Please see the edit in my question. I m puzzled about something in `firebug`

Answer (score 1):

"Because i still dont understand why i am unable to see those get and post requests in firebug's'net` tab"

I assume since you are requesting stuff with curl, it has nothing to do with firefox, since curl is a server-side library, therefore POSTs made by curl do not go through browser and firebug cannot see them.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing an already urlencoded string to PHP's [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php):

```
$post="code=$code&client_id=$client_id&client_secret=$client_sec&redirect_uri=$redirect_uri&grant_type=authorization_code";
$post=urlencode($post);
```

This messes up the value, Google's server can't properly parse it and therefore reports a missing parameter. Remove the `$post=urlencode($post);` line and see if it works *better*.